# JSON Stringify ignores nested objects on Redis publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose, redis

I am using Redis in my backend to scale subscriptions. I am using [this](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) library to implement redis on top of my javascript code. And using mongoose for the models.

During a redis publish, I have to stringify the objects that I get from mongoose. I parse them on the subscribing end and it all works well until there's a nested object in the object that needs to be stringify-ed.

So if my object is this:

```
{ subtitle: '',
   description: '',
   checklists:
    [ { _id: 5cee450c0fa29d0b54275da0, items: [] },
      { _id: 5cee455c0c31785b0875e09d, items: [] },
      { _id: 5cee47dc6d32e72c6411ce2d, items: [] } ],
   attachments: [],
   labels: [],
   _id: 5ced1af26547233798f943f6,
   title: 'asfasf',
   box: 5cece1c3e6c3c13ff098658d,
   workflow: 5cece1cbe6c3c13ff0986591,
}
```

I receive:

```
{ cardUpdated:
    { 
      subtitle: '',
      description: '',
      checklists: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
      attachments: [],
      labels: [],
      _id: '5ced1af26547233798f943f6',
      title: 'asfasf',
      box: '5cece1c3e6c3c13ff098658d',
      workflow: '5cece1cbe6c3c13ff0986591',
    } 
}
```

When I publish I use the following line:

```
pub.publish(types.CARD_UPDATED,
          JSON.stringify(
            { cardUpdated: await getUpdatedCardStats(checklist.card) },
          ));
```

Note: I know that I am wrapping the argument for stringify in `{}` and without it the nested objects would not be ignored, but I need to do that because I need the key property name on the subscription end i.e. I am using this publish command with different key names at several places.

Is there a way to about this to get the nested objects stringify-ed?

EDIT: Turns out, I was getting the proper full object as a string on the subscribing end of Redis, but it was actually `JSON.parse()` that was the culprit. After parsing, it completely ignores the nested objects. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
const value = JSON.stringify({
    cardUpdated: await getUpdatedCardStats(checklist.card)
});
pub.publish(types.CARD_UPDATED, value);
```

Comment: I actually did try it out. Turns out, the Redis publish might also be interfering in this. Before publishing I `console.log` the variable `value` before publishing and this is the output:

`{ "cardUpdated": { "_id":"5cece46350a2804a34f31de7", "checklists":[ { "_id":"5cee7e8176dce804e8d21e96", "items":[] }`

but when receiving it on the subscribed redis end, I get what I posted in the original post.

Comment: The console wasn't posting it properly. Thanks, now it's working

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JS object:

```js
{ _id: 5cee450c0fa29d0b54275da0, items: [] }
```

I think it's the output of `.toString()` of an object of type `{_id: ObjectId, items: any[]`, with ObjectId defined [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). In any case, the JSONification of this object is not trivial and that is why `JSON.stringify` simply outputs `[Object]`.

To bypass this limitation, you might implement a custom function to transform your object into one that can be trivially JSONified, possibly with the help of [ObjectId.toString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#ObjectId.toString).

Comment: The JSON that I stringify is received from mongoose probably that's why it doesn't wrap the `id` in string quotes. If the `id` is invalid in the nested object then it should also not work for the root object since there's an id in the root as well.